# How to convert String "TimeOfDay(00:00)" in TimeOfDay

Tags: flutter, dart, split, type-conversion

I have this String : `"TimeOfDay(00:00)"`. How can I convert it to a variable of type TimeOfDay to be able to get its '.hour' and '.minute' attributes?.

Another option would be split the string in a way to get only the values to after create a TimeOfDay in this way: "TimeOfDay(hour: (split hour), minute: (split minute)"

How can I reach that? Can be any of the two ways...

What I already tried:
`TimeOfDay(hour:int.parse(time.split(":")[0]),minute: int.parse(time.split(")")[1]));`
. But It gives me this error:

> Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
> TimeOfDay(00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```dart
time = time.split("(")[1].split(")")[0];
time = TimeOfDay(hour:int.parse(time.split(":")[0]),minute: int.parse(time.split(":")[1]));
```